# ng-repeat doesn't recognize scope data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have read about ng-repeat and tables in Angular but I still can't figure out something.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<h3>table</h3>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in userCars">
            <td>{{ car }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

my controller looks something like that:

```
app.controller('ManageCarsController', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {
    'use strict';
    (function () {
        console.log('code is getting here');
        $scope.userCars = [1,2,3];
        $scope.UserService = UserService;
    })();
```

and it leaves an empty table.
**BUT** if I change the code to be like this, it works (but it is not good for my usage):

```
app.controller('ManageCarsController', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.userCars = [1,2];
    (function () {
        $scope.UserService = UserService;
    })();
```

Comment: Why would you need IIFE inside the controller? even if you place the code as is, it will be invoked when controller gets instantiated. However do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Your question title asks about `ng-repeat` and tables, but the question seems to be about scope data and services. Please clarify.

Comment: There are no errors in console

Comment: How would you suggest me to change the title?

Comment: What do you find "less good" about the second example that works?

Comment: Please prepare a demo showcasing the issue.

Comment: I find "less good" (sorry for my English) that this is just a sample code, in the real code I actually need it in order to fetch the items that enter $scope.userCars. And I don't want my whole controller will be surrounded by IIFE

Comment: And as I said in another comment : even if I can find a workaround, I would like to understand why it doesn't work. I also thought that it connected to the fact that maybe the table is not rendered after the IIFE, but I am not sure how to render it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `IIFE`(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) helps you at all here. You should probably just remove it altogether which will in turn make everything work just fine for you

```
app.controller('ManageCarsController', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {
$scope.userCars = [1,2];
$scope.UserService = UserService;
```

If you really want to use `IIFE` you should place your entire code inside of it

```
'use strict';
(function () {
app.controller('ManageCarsController', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {
'use strict';
$scope.userCars = [1,2];
    $scope.UserService = UserService;
})();
```

Comment: The thing is that I just gave you a sample code, the real code needs an IIFE. And I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I mean, even if I can find a workaround, I would like to understand **why** it doesn't work. I also thought that it connected to the fact that maybe the table is not rendered after the IIFE, but I am not sure how to render it..